# Textbox alignment inside Groupbox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble with placing a textbox inside a groupbox (which is inside a grid). Since groupbox can contain only one children I created a grid to place labels and textboxes. The problem is - the textboxes created inside the groupboxes are left aligned according to the 2nd column of the grid inside the groupbox. I need the textboxes to be aligned left in the 2nd column of the main grid.

My `xaml` code

```
 <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
     <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label Content="Header"></Label>
     </GroupBox.Header>
     <Grid Grid.Row="0" Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="Label1:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Label2:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
     </Grid>
   </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Output for this code

[image]

You could see the textboxes in the column 1 of the main grid. If you look at the image, there is a radio button below that row which is in the second column. I need the textboxes to be aligned with that radiobutton I need them in the second column.

Comment: Try setting the ColumnWidth of the second Column to *

Comment: @FeDe Tried but not the intended result. It made the textbox occupy the remaining space.

Comment: Sou you want the textbox to be in on the right of that blue vertical line ?

Comment: @FeDe Yeah. That's what I need.

Comment: You cannot place the textboxes inside the second column of the grid that contains the groupbox

Comment: @JeffRSon Okay. But any other way to do that?

Comment: You need to tell more about what you want to achieve and show the outer of the groupbox

Comment: @JeffRSon I need the textbox to be in on the right of the blue vertical line

Comment: @madmax see my answer and tell me if it help pls

Comment: @madmax have you tried my solution?

Comment: You could set the width of the first column of the outer and the inner grid to the same fixed value

Answer (score 0):

`Width="Auto"` means the `Column` will automatically take a width.

You need to use something like this instead;

```
`<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`
```

Have a look at this [ColumnWidths](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a7e6591-1fae-4295-b68a-be97e8e53d06/difference-between-and-auto-in-wpf-grid?forum=wpf) for further explanation if needed.

To move the `TextBoxes` to the next `Column` in the main `Grid`, you need to remove them from the `GroupBox` and add them to the main `Grid` instead. You haven't posted the whole `XAML` so it's difficult to advise further.

Comment: Yeah. But if I remove the textboxes from the groupbox and add them to the main grid, I can have only one textbox since it takes up the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Alighment]

**if there are going to be only two columns in your grid then just below column definitions for your inner `Grid`:**

```
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

**A**s you want to align with the radio buttons that must be in second column of main grid then for `ColSpan=2` this will ***perfectly***.

> **When Width is set to `Auto` for a `ColumnDefinition` of a `Grid`** it
>   will take the `width` of element defined in the `Column` , So that's
>   the first thing you should remove a you are not using fixed `Width`
>   for `TextBoxes`.